# QTreeWidget itemClicked signal is emitted twice for double click

Tags: qt

In my QTreeWidget,
When I single click -> Single click Action has to be performed
When I double click -> double click action has to be performed (it is ok to perform single click action along with it).

But what happens is every time, double click is performed apart from the double click action, two times single click's slot is called.

I don't think this is a desirable behaviour of QTreeWidget in any case.

Can anyone suggest me how to workaround this, hopefully in a short, simple and clean way.

Comment: So I think you use itemDoubleClicked() and itemClicked() signals and so itemDoubleClicked() is called once and itemClicked() is called twice ?

Comment: @Dardanboy. Yes.

Comment: You could use a timer in the slot called with itemClicked() where you will wait for mouseDoubleClickInterval (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylehints.html#mouseDoubleClickInterval-prop). 

After the timer is finished, you will check if the itemDoubleClicked() has already been called (by putting a variable like m_isAlreadyDoubleClicked to true when it passed into the slot).
Otherway, if m_isAlreadyDoubleClicked is false, then it means the user clicked it only once.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when QTableWidget on double mouse click emits `itemClicked()` first and then `itemDoubleClicked()`. I used Dardan Iljazi's suggestion (see above), and I wish my code will be useful for somebody (tested on Qt 6.5 for Windows):

```cpp
//mainwindow.cpp

#include <QTimer>
#include <QStyleHints>

// ... other MainWindow methods implementation here

void MainWindow::on_treeWidget_itemClicked(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column)
{
    m_its_double_click = false; // property, declared in MainWindow

    QEventLoop evtLoop;
    // default system double click interval
    int dblClickInterval_ms = QApplication::styleHints()->mouseDoubleClickInterval();
    QTimer::singleShot(dblClickInterval_ms, &evtLoop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    evtLoop.exec(); // process other signals, slots end events until QTimer::singleShot fire 

    // if double click happened - prevent further slot execution
    if(m_its_double_click){
        qDebug() << "*** single clicked slot cancelled";
        return;
    }

    // code for single click
    qDebug() << "*** single clicked";
}


void MainWindow::on_treeWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem *item, int column)
{
    m_its_double_click = true; // set variable here for on_treeWidget_itemClicked()

    // code for double click
    qDebug() << "*** double clicked";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you do in case itemClicked is received, you might want to use currentItemChanged as a workaround instead. This might even be helpful for keyboard users. But this really depends on what you want to do after receiving itemClicked.